# Spectrum of a Lax Pair and conservation laws of a PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, integrable-systems, lax-pairs

I would like to ask a question that I had asked a few days ago on the site [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229287/spectrum-of-a-lax-pair-and-conservation-laws-of-a-pde)
and I still have not received an answer.

If we have a Lax operator, we know that the spectrum of this operator is conserved over time.

Suppose that we have an equation that admits $L_u$ as a Lax operator, then can we say that all the conservation laws of this equation can be written in terms of the spectrum of $L_u$ ? Especially if $L_u$ has a discrete spectrum ?

Thanks in advance.